# Fill height with flexbox inside a container

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm developing an intranet and I would like to have the content vertically and horizontally centered.

I have an website like this :

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- NAVBAR MENU -->
</div>
<!-- COULD BE container-fluid SOMETIMES -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- TITLE WITH A DROPDOWN BUTTON -->
      <h2>
          TITLE 
          <span class="pull-right">
             <button>BUTTON</button>
          </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- FOOTER -->
</div>
```

Content will always be the second child of `body` inside a div with `container` or `container-fluid` followed by a title attached with a dropdown menu on a button.

Important to know, my footer is static and its height is at 60px.

I'm trying to get a flexbox inside my 2nd container, AFTER the title part, which fill all of a remaining height. This way, only the pure content would be centered.

Unfortunately, I can't manage to get to this point.

I tried to set my body as a flexbox and manually setting all his children : My footer would hide the end of my page every time.

I tried to set a single flexbox in the easiest way possible, it would not fill the missing height.

`html` & `body` got `min-height: 100%;`. `align-items` & `justify-content` were set.

Also, I note that if I set html to `height:100%;`, it would show the scrollbar every time but then the single flexbox would get the full missing height but not get centered (and still have this footer problem).

I probably missed something or did a trick wrong ...

Thanks for any kind of help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Something like this? [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/L57nwm2u/)

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for the clean-up :)
@RicardoRuiz Near perfect, as yes, it's exactly what I want but my footer still hide some content when it's a long page. I tried adding some `margin-bottom` there and there but it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @RicardoRuiz for the answer.

It finally looks like the following snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.row,
.content,
.container {
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}
.container:first-child {
  border-color: green;
  height: 60px;
}
.container:nth-child(2) {
  border-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh-160px);
}
.container:last-child {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: red;
  height: 60px;
}
.row {
  border-color: yellow;
}
.content {
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  NAVBAR
</div>
<!-- COULD BE container-fluid SOMETIMES -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- TITLE WITH A DROPDOWN BUTTON -->
    <h2>
          TITLE 
          <span class="pull-right">
             <button>BUTTON</button>
          </span>
        </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dui sem, lacinia ac dictum ut, condimentum sit amet massa. Duis vel justo ac diam bibendum gravida vitae quis eros. Nam suscipit tellus in eros varius ullamcorper sed quis nulla. Mauris
      pharetra justo in lectus tincidunt, quis condimentum leo faucibus. Fusce quis magna laoreet, posuere metus in, scelerisque ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean eu elit et diam pellentesque mattis. Nulla facilisi. Cras scelerisque tortor dignissim
      lacus fringilla porta. Aliquam sagittis sit amet libero et ultrices. Praesent aliquet purus et ultrices semper. Integer sed lorem in augue volutpat convallis quis vel tellus. Duis venenatis orci id odio vehicula, eget feugiat lorem aliquam. Vivamus
      at tempus magna, mattis consequat sem. Aliquam porta sem vitae diam mollis, ut fringilla velit lacinia. Fusce ac suscipit elit. Proin lectus mauris, viverra sed lobortis at, ultrices vel ipsum. Cras non molestie diam. Donec lobortis lobortis magna,
      eget placerat mi tincidunt at. Quisque eget odio mauris. Nam eu tellus vitae nisl ornare finibus. Proin et enim aliquet, iaculis quam eleifend, mollis neque. Aenean auctor accumsan fermentum. Nam eget magna vehicula, tincidunt odio ut, vehicula
      arcu. Nulla sit amet turpis lacus. Sed iaculis, velit ac hendrerit imperdiet, ante lectus malesuada felis, quis tempus nibh nisl at dui. Aliquam laoreet accumsan varius. Vestibulum vel quam arcu. Praesent id semper eros, quis mollis dui. Etiam at
      sagittis lectus. Suspendisse in nisi bibendum nisl scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas nec scelerisque augue. Donec elementum consequat tempor. Sed porta viverra diam, non pellentesque odio scelerisque id. Vestibulum mollis nibh ut tellus pretium auctor.
      Aliquam erat volutpat. In sit amet nibh lobortis, maximus arcu eget, accumsan mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec non dolor sed dolor aliquet suscipit ut at quam. Ut dictum tellus in
      dui consectetur, eu egestas lacus sodales. Duis a luctus tellus, at efficitur magna. Quisque eleifend risus sit amet ipsum rhoncus egestas. In mauris lorem, ullamcorper quis laoreet sed, tempus vitae lectus. Integer neque leo, molestie ac aliquam
      id, lacinia et ligula. Pellentesque sagittis eleifend facilisis. Fusce nisl purus, elementum non urna in, egestas lacinia justo. Nunc libero dolor, vestibulum at tortor at, pellentesque vehicula mauris.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dui sem, lacinia ac dictum ut, condimentum sit amet massa. Duis vel justo ac diam bibendum gravida vitae quis eros. Nam suscipit tellus in eros varius ullamcorper sed quis nulla. Mauris
      pharetra justo in lectus tincidunt, quis condimentum leo faucibus. Fusce quis magna laoreet, posuere metus in, scelerisque ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean eu elit et diam pellentesque mattis. Donec lobortis lobortis magna, eget placerat mi tincidunt
      at. Quisque eget odio mauris. Nam eu tellus vitae nisl ornare finibus. Proin et enim aliquet, iaculis quam eleifend, mollis neque. Aenean auctor accumsan fermentum. Nam eget magna vehicula, tincidunt odio ut, vehicula arcu. Nulla sit amet turpis
      lacus. Sed iaculis, velit ac hendrerit imperdiet, ante lectus malesuada felis, quis tempus nibh nisl at dui. Aliquam laoreet accumsan varius. Vestibulum vel quam arcu. Praesent id semper eros, quis mollis dui. Etiam at sagittis lectus. Suspendisse
      in nisi bibendum nisl scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas nec scelerisque augue. Donec elementum consequat tempor. Sed porta viverra diam, non pellentesque odio scelerisque id. Vestibulum mollis nibh ut tellus pretium auctor. Aliquam erat volutpat. In
      sit amet nibh lobortis, maximus arcu eget, accumsan mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec non dolor sed dolor aliquet suscipit ut at quam. Ut dictum tellus in dui consectetur, eu egestas
      lacus sodales. Duis a luctus tellus, at efficitur magna. Quisque eleifend risus sit amet ipsum rhoncus egestas. In mauris lorem, ullamcorper quis laoreet sed, tempus vitae lectus. Integer neque leo, molestie ac aliquam id, lacinia et ligula. Pellentesque
      sagittis eleifend facilisis. Fusce nisl purus, elementum non urna in, egestas lacinia justo. Nunc libero dolor, vestibulum at tortor at, pellentesque vehicula mauris.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dui sem, lacinia ac dictum ut, condimentum sit amet massa. Duis vel justo ac diam bibendum gravida vitae quis eros. Nam suscipit tellus in eros varius ullamcorper sed quis nulla. Mauris
      pharetra justo in lectus tincidunt, quis condimentum leo faucibus. Fusce quis magna laoreet, posuere metus in, scelerisque ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean eu elit et diam pellentesque mattis. Donec lobortis lobortis magna, eget placerat mi tincidunt
      at. Quisque eget odio mauris. Nam eu tellus vitae nisl ornare finibus. Proin et enim aliquet, iaculis quam eleifend, mollis neque. Aenean auctor accumsan fermentum. Nam eget magna vehicula, tincidunt odio ut, vehicula arcu. Nulla sit amet turpis
      lacus. Sed iaculis, velit ac hendrerit imperdiet, ante lectus malesuada felis, quis tempus nibh nisl at dui. Aliquam laoreet accumsan varius. Vestibulum vel quam arcu. Praesent id semper eros, quis mollis dui. Etiam at sagittis lectus. Suspendisse
      in nisi bibendum nisl scelerisque pulvinar. Maecenas nec scelerisque augue. Donec elementum consequat tempor. Sed porta viverra diam, non pellentesque odio scelerisque id. Vestibulum mollis nibh ut tellus pretium auctor. Aliquam erat volutpat. In
      sit amet nibh lobortis, maximus arcu eget, accumsan mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec non dolor sed dolor aliquet suscipit ut at quam. Ut dictum tellus in dui consectetur, eu egestas
      lacus sodales. Duis a luctus tellus, at efficitur magna. Quisque eleifend risus sit amet ipsum rhoncus egestas. In mauris lorem, ullamcorper quis laoreet sed, tempus vitae lectus. Integer neque leo, molestie ac aliquam id, lacinia et ligula. Pellentesque
      sagittis eleifend facilisis. Fusce nisl purus, elementum non urna in, egestas lacinia justo. Nunc libero dolor, vestibulum at tortor at, pellentesque vehicula mauris.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dui sem, lacinia ac dictum ut, condimentum sit amet massa. Duis vel justo ac diam bibendum gravida vitae quis eros. Nam suscipit tellus in eros varius ullamcorper sed quis nulla. Mauris
      pharetra justo in lectus tincidunt, quis condimentum leo faucibus. Fusce quis magna laoreet, posuere metus in, scelerisque ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean eu elit et diam pellentesque mattis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```